# sxd-document / sxd-xpath failing to parse XML

Tags: xml, xpath, rust, xml-namespaces

I'm can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I have an external XML file that I'm trying to traverse via XPath.

My code is:

```rust
extern crate sxd_document;
extern crate sxd_xpath;

use std::fs;
use sxd_document::parser;
use sxd_xpath::{evaluate_xpath, Value};

fn main() {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("./spec/organisation.xml")
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

    // let package = parser::parse("<root>hello</root>").expect("failed to parse XML");
    let package = parser::parse(&contents).expect("failed to parse XML");
    let document = package.as_document();
    let value = evaluate_xpath(&document, "/root").expect("XPath evaluation failed");
    assert_eq!("hello", value.string());
}
```

The XML is:

```xml
<organisation xml:id="a17649">
    <code rdf:resource="http://pbs.gov.au/code/manufacturer">CU</code>
    <title>Care Pharmaceuticals Pty Limited</title>
    <address>
        <dbk:street>Suite 303, Level 3, 59-75 Grafton Street</dbk:street>
        <dbk:city>Bondi Junction</dbk:city>
        <dbk:state>NSW</dbk:state>
        <dbk:postcode>2022</dbk:postcode>
        <effective>
            <date>2018-12-01</date>
        </effective>
    </address>
    <contact>
        <dbk:phone>1800 788 870</dbk:phone>
        <effective>
            <date>2018-12-01</date>
        </effective>
    </contact>
    <effective>
        <date>2012-08-27</date>
    </effective>
</organisation>
```

The stack trace looks like:

```
     Running `target/debug/pbs`
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to parse XML: Error { location: 50, errors: {UnknownNamespacePrefix} }', libcore/result.rs:1009:5
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::unix::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace
             at libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:49
   1: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
             at libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:71
             at libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:59
   2: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at libstd/panicking.rs:211
   3: std::panicking::default_hook
             at libstd/panicking.rs:227
   4: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at libstd/panicking.rs:476
   5: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at libstd/panicking.rs:390
   6: rust_begin_unwind
             at libstd/panicking.rs:325
   7: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at libcore/panicking.rs:77
   8: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at libcore/macros.rs:26
   9: <core::result::Result<T, E>>::expect
             at libcore/result.rs:835
  10: pbs::main
             at src/main.rs:14
  11: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
             at libstd/rt.rs:74
  12: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at libstd/rt.rs:59
             at libstd/panicking.rs:310
  13: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:102
  14: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at libstd/panicking.rs:289
             at libstd/panic.rs:392
             at libstd/rt.rs:58
  15: std::rt::lang_start
             at libstd/rt.rs:74
  16: main
  17: __libc_start_main
  18: _start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML parsing code should work in the happy path, when the XML content is correct.

Although it works with no problem in the happy path, since you use `expect` in the code instead of error handling, the program panics in the error scenario.

You can change the code to the following to print the error better:

```
let package = parser::parse(&contents);

match package {
    Ok(package) => {
        let document = package.as_document();
        let value = evaluate_xpath(&document, "/root").expect("XPath evaluation failed");
        println!("value: {:?}", value);
    }
    Err(err) => {
        println!("{:?}", err);
    }
}
```

After that fix, you will notice that the code prints an `UnknownNamespacePrefix` error.

This error occurs when the XML content has namespaces that are not declared in the XML file itself.

In your XML file, you need to specify your namespaces, which you did not for the following:

```
<organisation xml:id="a17649">
```

You need to add the namespace:

```
<organisation xml:id="a17649" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Even once you have declared `rdf` namespace like this, you are also using the `dbk` namespace which probably depends on your project itself. You will need to specify this namespace as well:

```
<organisation xml:id="a17649" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dbk="/path/to/dbk">
```

After these changes, your problem should be solved

Comment: Author of sxd_xpath and sxd_document here: this answer is correct. I'd welcome an issue filed against sxd_document to somehow add the ability to parse this type of XML.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message I would expect that you need to declare the `rdf` namespace before you using it on the `rdf:resource` attribute name.

(Your problem doesn't have anything to do with XPath -- it fails while trying to parse the XML, before any XPath code is being run.)

Answer (score 1):

Your XML file uses the non-standard `rdf` namespace but does not define it. You need to define the namespace in the XML:

```xml
<organisation xml:id="a17649"
              xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
```

Some XML parsers allow you to declare namespaces in your code, outside of the XML document, but I haven't found anything like that after a quick look in the `sxd_document` [docs](https://docs.rs/sxd-xpath/0.4.2/sxd_xpath/).

Comment: Author of sxd_xpath and sxd_document here: this answer is correct. I'd welcome an issue filed against sxd_document to somehow add the ability to parse this type of XML.